# problem with inherit a view - Odoo [v13] Module

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I want to inherit a form view from the module mrp.production, I use odoo 13

I have installed a personalized module, my module is intalled without any error, and some of my functions works form inherited module (mrp.production) but my view is not listed in inherited views.

My manifest it is ok

Thanks in advance for your comments.

here is my view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_mrp_production_by_lot_inherit_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mrp.production.by.lot.inherit.form</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.production</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_production_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

I found it, my view was marked inactive after a migration from v12 to v13 just i changed it in the database to active (it is a boolean field) and works now!!

Comment: Check the external id you are adding in this XML code is actually the one that you want to inherit? and the second thing is to add some fields for this inherited view also.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was on the migration, for some reason after migration, some views was marked as inactive.